# Using Mailto link can I add the current page in the outlook mail body if possible then how ? in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

using mailto hyperlink I want to add the Current page in the outlook mail body ,using JavaScript or asp.net .

Please give ideas so I can try that in our program  .

Thanks for the help ...

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code :

```
  <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=this is subject&body=I will go in to body" target="_top">
```

Send Mail

values are appended just like you do in querystring. Hope this helps.

Edit: If you want current page url in body then replace I will go in to body with your current page url. It can be done on server (C#) or on client using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that

Here `.email` is the class on the link on which you are calling mailto attribute

It should look like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="email">Mail Here</a>
```

And `ContentId` is the id of any control whose text you want to append in the body.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body=$("#ContentId").text();
    $(".email").attr("href", "mailto:?subject=...;body"+body+window.location);
});
```